# How to create a desktop application using flashlite as front end?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, desktop-application, flashlite

I'm looking for information on how to create a desktop application that runs flashlite for the front end UI but has a lot of c++ code for the back end.

Any pointers is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a few projects which allow a Flash frontend with a C++ backend:

- [FlasCC](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/games/articles/compiling-opengl-games.html)
- [hxcpp](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/hxcpp)